# How do I set the correct time in my Google Kubernetes Engine container? Do I need to configure NTP?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

The containers in my k8s cluster need to be set to the correct time with high accuracy, meaning that I can only handle 10s of milliseconds difference max.

Do I need to setup NTP configuration for the containers on Google Kubernetes Engine to make sure that that clock in the containers is set to the correct time?

Answer (score 9):

No. You don't need to do any of your own NTP configuration. Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) runs a timesyncd service in each of the containers. The service is pre-configured to sync up with [Google's NTP servers](https://developers.google.com/time/). If you want to set the time yourself, you need to stop the timesyncd service and override the time settings manually.

Comment: thank you for the follow up. Do you have any google documentation you can reference, where they mention that GKE nodes do this?

Comment: There is no official reference about it, however you can verify it on your own. Just use SSH to access node instances, then run `date`, `timedatectl show-timesync --all` or even `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service`.