# Correcting clock skew in a GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

I have the following alert configured in prometheus:

```
alert: ClockSkewDetected
expr: abs(node_timex_offset_seconds{job="node-exporter"})
  > 0.03
for: 2m
labels:
  severity: warning
annotations:
  message: Clock skew detected on node-exporter {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }}. Ensure NTP is configured correctly on this host.
```

This alert is [part of](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/blob/773a9c73e9e1a817d079cf6db13603a1cb830c8b/jsonnet/kube-prometheus/alerts/node.libsonnet#L38-L50) the default `kube-prometheus` stack which I am using.

I find this alert fires for around 10 mins every day or two.

I'd like to know how to deal with this problem (the alert firing!). It's suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792742/how-do-i-set-the-correct-time-in-my-google-kubernetes-engine-container-do-i-nee) that I shouldn't need to run NTP (via a daemonset I guess) myself on GKE.

I'm also keen to use the `kube-prometheus` defaults where possible - so I'm unsure about increasing the `0.03` value.

Comment: The offset value being monitored is already being set by the time manager on the GKE VM so no need to run something else. Time on a VM can skew due to high load on the VM guest or host, although 30ms sounds pretty high.

Comment: I had wondered if it might also be due to my use of preemptible VMs (with new ones coming and going regularly). This is a small hobby cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the answer, [instances in GCP are preconfigured to have their own NTP server synced](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/configure-ntp), so there shouldn't be any need to use DaemonSets to manually configure them.

It might be the case that the clock is skewing on [live migrations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) and it catches up automatically but not without triggering the alert. However, this theory only applies for non-preemptible instances.

[Some events on GCE instances are supposed to trigger the Clock Skew Daemon](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/634) that will eventually correct changes initiated by the user (or a process action on behalf of the user), so if this is happening in your nodes, that's another possibility.

Regardless of the aforementioned theories and since nodes are managed resources in GKE, I think you have a pretty solid case for the [GKE support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) to investigate as this might be an implementation detail.

Comment: Sadly I don't have a Google Support plan (this is my personal cluster/account) but thanks for the links and detailed response all the same.

Comment: I have a customer experiencing this, and do have enterprise support with GCP, so may create a ticket and get definitive answers. If I learn anything new I'll share with the group.

Comment: @MikeS. Did you learn anything from GCP Support? I'm dealing with this Clock Skew issue right now on a cluster of preemptible nodes.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this alert overkill described above can also happen when you have no NTP running anywhere yourself. As stated by @yyyyahir correctly, Google manages NTP for you.

In that case it ended up being a bug in the Prometheus Operator [1] [2] [3] reporting this wrong, which can be fixed by upgrading. There is a lot more details in the issues linked for anyone interested.

I hope answering here makes someone else have one headache less :-)

[1] https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/21941

[2] https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/495

[3] https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/21899/commits/bde27aa9f8ff029e92f9c2b307d61a5fcbf6f1d6#diff-c4d7cc51f0e4f93d65e4fe1374ac0cbbad420ccdeb091ba46d6d782dd1e37eab