# Time Synchronization in GKE Auto-pilot Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing, autopilot

I had created Auto-Pilot GKE Cluster, Does it have time synchronization between node/pods?

Does time synchronization enabled between GKE Auto-pilot cluster nodes/pods?
Or do we have to configure NTP/Chronyd Service manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48792742/5529712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the nodes are configured to use `metadata.google.internal` for NTP.

Comment: Can you provide official document for this?